# Cardinality of the set $\{(\aleph_{\omega_1})^\kappa : 1 \leq \kappa < \aleph_{\omega_1}\}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to figure out a way to answer the following task:

> Suppose that for every $ \alpha, \beta < \omega_1 $ there exists a $ \gamma < \omega_1 $ such that $ \aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_\beta} = \aleph_\gamma $.
>   Compute the cardinality of the following set $$\{(\aleph_{\omega_1})^\kappa : 1 \leq \kappa < \aleph_{\omega_1}\}$$

Obviously the answer is $ \leq \aleph_{\omega_1} $, but I don't have any great ideas on how to pursue the answer - should I seek the other inequality? How do i use the assumption about exponentiating cardinals?

I would appreciate some hints

Comment: Consistently the bound can be smaller, for example, GCH holds below $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, then by Silver's theorem it holds at $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ too. Thus the cardinality of the set is bounded above by $\aleph_1$. Since for any $\omega_1\leq \beta<\aleph_{{\omega_1}}, \aleph_{\omega_1}^\beta =\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$.

Comment: Why do you just assume GCH?

Comment: Because in this case, it is hopeless trying to prove some lower bound in ZFC, for example, ZFC can't prove that the size of the set is greater than $\aleph_1$ (because it is consistent that the size is smaller or equal to $\aleph_1$). But that doesn't rule out some other better upper bounds in ZFC.

Comment: But can't it be solved using just the assumption mentioned in the task? I know it's somehow related to GCH, but that's part of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks as if I'm going to answer my own question.

It's not difficult to prove the following result, knowing Tarski's and Bukovský's identities for exponentiating cardinals:

> Suppose $ \lambda < \kappa $. If for all $ \mu < \kappa ~ \mu^\lambda < \kappa$, then
>   $$\kappa^\lambda = \begin{cases}\kappa &\lambda < \operatorname{cf}(\kappa)\\\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So what the assumption gives us is that if $ \lambda, \mu < \kappa = \aleph_{\omega_1}$ and by this lemma, this set will contain only two elements: $  \aleph_{\omega_1}, \aleph_{\omega_1}^{\omega_1} $

I would appreciate a verification of this answer